# ajax - Does .load() execute PHP located in between the loaded div tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello and apologies if I am wasting your time with such a simple question. Basically I want to know if PHP code between  tags will execute if loaded with AJAX's .load() function?

Example (PHP):

```
<div id='example'>
    <?php
       echo "Hello world!";
    ?>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#changeme').load('example.php #example');
```

Would the inner HTML of #changeme be loaded as 'Hello world!'?

Comment: what happened when you tested it?

Comment: PHP is executed before anything is sent to the browser, so yes.

Comment: rtfm I'm away from my development machine for a few days so I am unable to test it myself
@AbraCadaver excellent, thank you!